# Python win32com - Call TextBox by Name?

Tags: excel, textbox, pywin32

I am trying in vain to get the name of a TextBox in MS Excel using pywin32, I have tried recording a macro and I get the following tips, but I cannot translate them from VBA to python. In the sample below I select the Textbox and rename it, all I want is to be able to refer to them by name and I figure this gets me close.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 2")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "TextBox 3"
```

This is what I have in python so far to this end.

```
import win32com.client as win32 
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\users\\khillstr\\Testing\\Scripts\\Book1.xlsx")
excel.Visible = True

ws = wb.Worksheets

for w in ws:
    print w.Name
    w.Activate
    canvas = w.Shapes
    for shp in canvas:
        if shp.TextFrame.Characters:
            print shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
```

Comment: I have a similar issue -- I need to read the data from a textbox in excel, but I am not running windows, so I don't think I can use the win32com library. Does anyone know another solution that would work in *NIX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for shp in canvas:
    print shp.name
```

Name is a read/write property for textbox shapes.  You can get and set the name using that property.  Tested in Excel 2010.

Comment: I get an error when I try that, object has no attribute 'name'.

Comment: That is because it is Name not name. Thanks again for your help, it was too easy again.